# How do I use the pearsonr function in scipy to find the correlation and P-Value of dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, scipy, correlation

I have some Python code below:

```
a = dict.values(histodict[str(start)])
b = dict.values(histodict[str(end)])
print pearsonr(a,b)
```

Both variables a and b will print properly as a list when the script is instructed to do so but they will not respond in the pearsonr function in scipy.

I am wondering why this doesn't work. The error returned is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "BlackBox.py", line 32, in <module>
print corr(a,b)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 1596, in pearsonr
mx = x.mean()
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

And since this code in its current form will obviously not work, how do I use the pearsonr function in scipy to return the correlation and P-value of dictionary values?

Comment: You can just use `histdict[str(start)].values()` instead of making a copy of the dictionary.  Can you show us the contents of `a` and `b`?

Comment: a is a list with the values ['17633200', '214.0', '214.50', '212.38', '214.01', '213.43'] and b is a list with the values ['17633200', '214.0', '214.50', '212.38', '214.01', '213.43']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment your values are not integers / floats:

```
a = [float(x) for x in histodict[str(start)].itervalues()]
b = [float(x) for x in histodict[str(end)].itervalues()]
print pearsonr(a,b)
```

Comment: Now it returns the error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BlackBox.py", line 28, in <module>
    a = [int(x) for x in histodict[str(start)].itervalues()]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '214.0'

Comment: @BlackBoxTrader: Oh sorry I edited my answer, change int to float

Comment: Okay so when I run this code compared to the a and b values before the float values tend to be slightly different because of the nature of the float type. How will this effect my calculations?

Comment: It shouldn't affect it very much the pearson correlation is looking for a linear correlation between the two lists.